# Cloud Functions for Firebase timeout

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Simple cloud function to get database data is not working.

`getusermessage()` is not working

Error:

> Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Index.JS for getting database result.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into the
// Realtime Database under the path /messages/:pushId/original
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
  // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
    // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
  });
});

// Listens for new messages added to /messages/:pushId/original and creates an
// uppercase version of the message to /messages/:pushId/uppercase
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onWrite(event => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original = event.data.val();
      console.log('Uppercasing', event.params.pushId, original);
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
      // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
      // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
      return event.data.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
    });

var db = admin.database();
exports.getUserMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
var query = db.ref("messages").orderByKey();
query.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var key = childSnapshot.key;
      // childData will be the actual contents of the child
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  });
});  
});
```

What am O doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You didn't say which of your three functions is timing out, but I'll take a guess at which one.  Your HTTPS function `getUserMessage` isn't generating a response to the client.  Cloud Functions will wait for 60 seconds (by default) for it to generate a response, and if it doesn't, it will kill the function and leave that message in the log.

Every code path in an HTTPS function should generate some response to the client.

Comment: @Dough you guess is right, But I didn't get your answer as I said I am trying cloud function. Can you point out what I am doing wrong in `getUserMessage()`

Comment: As I said, your function isn't generating a response to the client.  You absolutely need to send a response.  See the documentation for HTTPS functions for more details, especially the section called "Terminate HTTP Functions".  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: @twister_void you are missing a return statement in the function Doug mentions

Comment: @J.Doe returning a promise from an https function won't keep it alive until it resolves, like other types of functions.  You have to return a response.  See the docs I referenced.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm having a similar issue here, but as I understood it, as long as the res.send/end/redirect occur in the then/catch or callback, this is sufficient. You seem to imply the response should be returned regardless to account for a resolution after 60s. is that so? how would that code run if you return Promise?

Comment: HTTPS functions don't terminate by returning promises like other types of functions.  They terminate by sending a response to the client.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timeout and memory using `runWith` during function declaration,

`exports.getUserMessage = functions.runWith({ memory: '2GB', timeoutSeconds: 360 }).https.onRequest(`