# Google Cloud functions activate

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I would like to activate my Google Cloud function.

[Test function](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-starting-cloudfunctions/index.html#3)
Testing is working fine, but it only runs for 1-2 hours max and then its not active any more. 
It is a nodeJS-backend module waiting for calls and answering these.  I need it to be running 24/7.

Thanks

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify some of the question?  What does it mean to "activate"?

Comment: I want the module to be running all the time - when I run "Test function" it only runs for some hours. I can pay for it, but want to know where to switch it ON. There is no crash log, so the "Test function" seems to auto-terminate.

Comment: What makes you think its "not running"?  My understanding of Cloud Functions is that you register a function that is assured to execute when called.  You define some code and register that code (handler) with the cloud function.  You then invoke the function and it runs.  Your code is a request handler ... it is invoked only when requests arrive.  You can't have continuously running logic in a cloud function.

Comment: when using "https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever" on my own server it was running 24/7 to respond when called, when using "test function" the request handler is only active for 1-2 hours and working.... and why is it called "TEST" anyway? I need a normal request handler

Comment: Ah I got it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363313/cloud-functions-for-firebase-timeout helped me. My function was not running correctly, though no errors were thrown. You need to return "res.send('some message')" at the end of your function, otherwise execution does not give a 200 code. Test is only ONE request to your handler, function should already work 24/7 on deploy!

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Functions aren't minded to run constantly. They're supposed to run just in the moment when something trigger the Function and then stop. As you mentioned you are running them using the test of the console. I would suggest you to trigger them with the Http link that you can find in the trigger tab, you can find more information about how to ser triggers properly in this [Events and Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers) doc.

Comment: Thanks. In case my google cloud functions crashed, how can I reset the whole environment?

Comment: Cloud function are serverless. This means that you cannot act directly on the infrastructure because it is handled automatically, if your crash function Cloud Function is automatically responsible for executing your function on a new machine and healing the hanged machine. you can read more about that here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#stateless_functions

Comment: Thanks. I tried to exit with "throw new Error('I failed')" and then the docs say a cold start should take place, but only when I press "Test function" my function really resets. Throwing error just exits it, but seems like memory and environment is not reset.

Comment: Yes as this documentation states the environment can be reutilized, and usually so it is. You should mind that with Cloud Functions you have no control on the environment or the machine, it will do cold starts, or reutilize the environment as its needed by the system. When you press Test function it is possible that your function runs on a new machine during the Test, but the main function remains on the same machine. If you need control on the environment i would suggest you using Cloud App Engine or just an GCE instance.